# how to give the default path in gwt

Tags: gwt

i m creating  a project in gwt (point) is project name ...
i want to store a image in point/war/images folder, whaich i gave the full path like C:\Documents and Settings\computer\workspace\m\war\images\ tthe the iamge will stored in images folder but i want to give the default path
i give "../war/images/"  as default path, but this give me error (he system cannot find the path specified  )

can any body help to give the default path

Answer (score 0):

Usually you put images in the `war/images` directory, and you access them like

```
Image img = new Image("images/my_image.jpg")
```

You may also read [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3765036adb21c86e), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502166/where-do-i-put-static-files-for-gwt-app-war-folder-or-public-folder).

Comment: This does not work. I just tried this, and `war/images` is deleted upon compilation.