# Intellij idea: Gwt cannot find CSS classes

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, intellij-idea

I am running Intellij Idea on Ubuntu, where I am trying out a GWT project. I am trying out the StockWatcher project, but whenever I add css classes to it, it complains they are not found. **I searched for the same problem, but changing paths to CSS didn't help**.  Any ideas. 
Screenshot :

[image]

Here is the gwt.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
  "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='stockwatcher'>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>
  <entry-point class='com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher'/>
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StockWatcher.css">
    <title>StockWatcher</title>
    <script src="stockwatcher/stockwatcher.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>StockWatcher</h1>
<div id="stockList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other information required, kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Is it just IntelliJ that's complaining or does it actually not compile and not work as expected?

Comment: @Baz : Both, For example, the CSS style is supposed to be Italic, but it does not look that way. Check screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/46vzzig3n/

Comment: Has the style been applied to the element and can you see the style of it in your browsers inspector?

Comment: @Baz : Now when I checked it in firebug, the css file itself is not found.... Any idea why is that? I have edited my main post and pasted content from firebbug. Kindly check it out.

Comment: looking at your screenshot and the firebug error message I would say that it can not find the folder: css containing the StockWatcher.css. Could you remove the `css/`?

Comment: @Rotan075 : I have tried StockWatcher.css, css/StockWatcher.css and /css/StockWatcher.css. I am just wondering which magic combination is remaining. Also, Idea generally suggests paths, but for GWT project, it's not even telling me what's the parent-dir for resources. Trying now, restarting to be sure.

Comment: @Rotan075 : Okay, a restart helped, seems like the Refresh page thing GWT is so proud of does not work properly. But Intellij still shows warning. Any ideas why?

Comment: To be precise, where do you add the CSS to which file? And what is the exact error that you get? @WeareBorg

Comment: @Rotan075 : After restarting the server, the css file was loaded, so my original argument that CSS is not loaded is void, bceause I was refreshing all the time rather than restarting. Now I only get error in IDE `Unknown css class class_name` .

Comment: @WeareBorg [IntelliJ gwt plugin - why do I get “unknown css class” errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996931/intellij-gwt-plugin-why-do-i-get-unknown-css-class-errors). Same exact problem.

Comment: @Baz : First thing I tried, literally..Also, the answering person does not know much about Intellij as the user says `Sorry I don't have any idea about IntelliJ but it works perfect in gwt using HTML/JSP as well as gwt.xml.` .

Comment: @WeareBorg It appears to have worked for the OP though, as the errors went away.

Comment: @WeareBorg what happens when you click the light bulb in front of your error and select "Create CSS class 'name_of_your_css_class'" This will add the desired class to the CSS stylesheet with no formatting properties and display the newly added class so the formatting properties can be added.

Comment: @Rotan075 : No such option available. check screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/kojeluv4n/

Comment: @WeareBorg It should show the light bulb. See docs: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/GWT_IDEA.html

Comment: @Baz : I hear you, it is not working unfortunately. I added in xml, `  <stylesheet src="/css/stockwatcher.css"/>` , and in html changed path from `StockWatcher.css` to `css/Stockwatcher.css`, didn't help. Screenshot : 
http://postimg.org/image/hbv71q017/

Comment: Final and last trick you might use (otherwise I am out of options) Try to click on: `File | Invalidate Caches` and restart your Intellj Idea @WeareBorg

Comment: @Rotan075 : Downloaded the udpated version of Intelli, cleared the config directory, and : http://postimg.org/image/bt76cd32d/