# Path for images folder in GWT project

Tags: image, gwt

I have the following line of code to set the URL of an image I want to display

```
img.setUrl("images/img1.jpg");
```

Where should I place my images folder in order for it to get picked up correctly.  Currently I have it in my WEB-INF folder but this does not appear to work.  I get the error on my console "WARNING: No file found for: /images/img1.jpg" 
 I created my project using Eclipse and I have not changed any folder structure.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22631764/1915920

Answer (score 3):

You should make a folder named `images` under your `war/project_folder` and place the images there.

And while setting the Url you shoud do

```
image.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"images/im1.jpg");
```

You can use either  GWT.getModuleBaseURL() or GWT.getHostPageBaseURL().

Comment: see also http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions (Guidelines 6.)

Comment: This does not work. I just tried it in Eclipse Kepler + GWT 2.6 and anything added to `war/project_folder` is deleted upon compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a public folder (named "public") alongside with folders "client" and "server". The content of the public folder will be copied into the war.

>src

  >com

    >test

    >client

--->public

        >images

    >server

    >shared

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use absolut URL rather than relative URL by using `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`. If you want to use relative path, then your image should be in the war as described by your relative path.

In your case it is

```
war->images->img1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the images in the web app directory.

You can check your web app directory here
Proeect --> Properties --> Google --> web Application

Here you will find the WAR directory

So in this directory , you need to put your images.

You can put the image directly or else you can make folders as you want

sample -

```
image path -->   WebContent/img/pics/recent/data/1/1.jpg 

String imagePath = "/img/pics/recent/data/1/1.jpg" ;

Image img = new Image(imagePath);
```

NOTE :- How ever GWT Image does not understand absolute file path , you need to use relative file path