# Error "Core SmartClient JavaScript libraries appear not to be loaded" with smartGWT

Tags: javascript, libraries, smartgwt, smartclient, loaded

With smart gwt 4 when I run the application I get the following error

Core SmartClient JavaScript libraries appear not to be loaded.
If inheriting the NoScript SmartGWT modules, verify that the HTML file includes  tags to load the SmartClient module .js files from the appropriate location within the WAR.
By default these files are present under [GWT app name]/sc/modules/.

com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: Core SmartClient JavaScript libraries appear not to be loaded.
If inheriting the NoScript SmartGWT modules, verify that the HTML file includes  tags to load the SmartClient module .js files from the appropriate location within the WAR.
By default these files are present under [GWT app name]/sc/modules/.

I have set the following jar in my classpath

smartgwt.jar

smartgw-skin.jar

and add the inherits in my .gwt.xml file

And in my jps file I add the script

Comment: the script i added is : <script src='showcase/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js'></script>
<script src='showcase/sc/modules/ISC_Drawing.js'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the paths are correct and the files are there in your WAR.  It's also important to understand how the GWT directory structure works inside WAR files (the relative paths are not always what you think they should be).

Have you tried using `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` or `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()` for your paths?

Check these other posts for more info:

- [Path for images folder in GWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071517/path-for-images-folder-in-gwt-project)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/PxdjqjMIlVY