# Changes to the CSS and HTML files in webapp directory not being picked up by SuperDevMode

Tags: gwt, livereload, gwt-super-dev-mode

I think GWT is supposed to automatically pick up and reload changes to the app-wide HTML and CSS files, which reside in the `webapp` folder. However, in my case this is simply not the case and GWT says "skipped compile because no input files have changed". I am not sure where I should edit to let those files be watched as well.

This project was initialized using the old `gwt-maven` plugin from https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html.

The program arguments on launch is the following: `-war app/target/App-1.0-SNAPSHOT -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl index.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 com.example.www.App.App`.

Or did I simply not understand it correctly and GWT is just not supposed to watch for changes in the `webapp` folder? This would really hinder the pace of frontend development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT compiles .java (input) files to javascript.
So if you only modify a css file there is no need to recompile to js.
However, when creating the war file, files in `public` dir may be updated.

Comment: I see. Though that means the only way to reflect those changes would be to create the WAR file again then (essentially needing to relaunch the SuperDevMode)? So GWT really wants you to put as much UI/styling code into individual widgets as possible

Comment: What if I still want to write some application-wide CSS but don't want to relaunch every time to reflect the changes. Do I need to use CSS injection or something like that?

Comment: Not really, you have options depending on your needs. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502166/where-do-i-put-static-files-for-gwt-app-war-folder-or-public-folder).

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `src/main/webapp` is not watched for changes. The `maven-war-plugin` will process those files into `target/${finalName}` (and copy dependencies to it's `WEB-INF/lib` and the project classes to `WEB-INF/classes`), and the embedded server in DevMode will serve them as a webapp.

The way to update them is to run `mvn war:exploded -Dgwt.compiler.skip` (or possibly `mvn package -Dgwt.compiler.skip -DskipTests`); and then you'll tell DevMode to reload the webapp (from it's "Jetty" tab)